# assertion error on passing EasyMock.anyObject()

Tags: junit4, easymock

I have two method call back to back based upon some processing. Both are returning some event when I try to pass `EasyMock.anyObject()`. When executing the test case `null` value is coming inside the method parameter. I am new to EasyMock. Can someone please see what mistake I am doing?

Error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call usrAuthenticationViaFormAction.submit(null, null, null):
    usrAuthenticationViaFormAction.setCredentialsToFlowScope(): expected: 1, actual: 0
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:94)
    at com.shc.ecom.usr.web.action.USRAuthenticationViaFormAction$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d3989200.submit(<generated>)
    at com.shc.ecom.test.usr.TestloginlFlow.testWhenServiceIsNotNullSubmitAuthenticationFailure(TestloginlFlow.java:438)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Method:

```java
class UsrAuthenticationViaFormAction {

    public  Event submit( RequestContext context,  Credential credential, MessageContext messageContext) {

        //          if (!checkLoginTicketIfExists(context)) {
        //              return returnInvalidLoginTicketEvent(context, messageContext);
        //          }

        if (isRequestAskingForServiceTicket(context)) {
            return grantServiceTicket(context, credential);
        }

        return createTicketGrantingTicket(context, credential, messageContext);
    }
}
```

Test case:

```java
public void test(){
    usrAuthenticationViaFormAction = EasyMock.createMock("usrAuthenticationViaFormAction", USRAuthenticationViaFormAction.class);

    Event event = new Event(this, "success");
    try {
        EasyMock.expect(usrAuthenticationViaFormAction.isRequestAskingForServiceTicket((EasyMock.anyObject())))
                        .andReturn(false).anyTimes();
        EasyMock.expect(usrAuthenticationViaFormAction.createTicketGrantingTicket((EasyMock.anyObject()),
                        EasyMock.anyObject(), EasyMock.anyObject())).andReturn(event).anyTimes();
        EasyMock.expect(usrInitialFlowSetupAction.doExecute(EasyMock.anyObject())).andReturn(event);
        EasyMock.replay(usrInitialFlowSetupAction);
        EasyMock.expect(usrAuthenticationViaFormAction.setCredentialsToFlowScope()).andReturn(false);
        EasyMock.replay(usrAuthenticationViaFormAction);
        EasyMock.expect(usrAuthenticationViaFormAction.submit(EasyMock.anyObject(), EasyMock.anyObject(), EasyMock.anyObject())).andReturn(new Event(this, "authenticationFailure")).anyTimes();
        EasyMock.replay(usrAuthenticationViaFormAction);
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here. where is actual method call? when you set the behavior , do the replay and verify it afterwards. Please go through the  Easymock tutorial.                                                                                                    EasyMock.expect(usrAuthenticationViaFormAction.isRequestAskingForServiceTicket((EasyMock.anyObject(RequestContext.class))))
                        .andReturn(false);    Pass specific object instead of using Easymock.anyObject().

Answer (score 0):

To add to PKR's comment - the UsrAuthenticationViaFormAction.submit method you have mentioned above is never being called by the Test class.

When you do

```
 usrAuthenticationViaFormAction = EasyMock.createMock("usrAuthenticationViaFormAction", USRAuthenticationViaFormAction.class);
```

usrAuthenticationViaFormAction is assigned a mock object. This is a dynamically generated class by EasyMock that has no *real* implementation.

Subsequently when you do

```
 EasyMock.expect(usrAuthenticationViaFormAction.submit(EasyMock.anyObject(), EasyMock.anyObject(), EasyMock.anyObject())).andReturn(new Event(this, "authenticationFailure")).anyTimes();
```

the submit method that is called is on the *mock* object. This just informs the easy mock framework that you expect this method to be called later on during the test execution. it does not actually invoke the real submit method.